# Rails: Why does Prawn give me an Unkown Font Error when loading a custom font for my PDF?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, fonts, prawn, prawnto

I'm using `Prawn`/ `Prawnto_2` to generate PDFs for my Rails app. I'm trying to load a custom font, but keep getting the following error:

> Prawn::Errors::UnknownFont in MyControllers#report

I placed the fonts in my `assets/font` dir, restarted the server, but no luck.

My `report.pdf.prawn`:

```
    font_families.update(
        "Garamond" => {
          :normal      => "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/fonts/Garamond/AGaramondPro-Regular.otf",
        })

font("Garamond", :size => 10) do
    text "Hello PDF"
end
```

It does work for Open Sans strangely, but have no luck with other fonts. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Apparently it does not accept all fonts, as some seem to work and some not...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prawn doesn't currently support OpenType Format (OTF) fonts (see [this Github issue](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn/issues/470) for details).  If you're using an external font for your PDF, you're better off using a TrueType Font (TTF) file.